# Migrations Error = No changes detected in app 'myapp'

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have included 'myapp' at myproj/setting.py INSTALLED APP, and I have tried to add some model and stuff but it still return the error No changes detected in app 'myapp', what should I do?????

this is the step that lead to the error

```
    hostname $ python pip install django
    hostname $ django-admin startproject myproj
    hostname $ cd myproj
    hostname $ python manage.py startapp myapp
    hostname $ python manage.py makemigrations myapp
```

Comment: You will have to show us your code.

Comment: `startapp` will not create any models and it will also not add the application to `INSTALLED_APPS`, the steps you have given do not reproduce the issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must have to write your application name in settings.py `INSTALLED_APP`. Then run `python manage.py makemigrations myapp`, So it will create migrations file. so check whether it is created or not in your migration folder of your app, if it is available then run `python manage.py migrate`.
Let me know it is works or not.

Comment: Thank you. I read many stackoverflow posts for this but this worked perfectly.!